# Upon selecting open jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, selectable

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.rota  td').live('click', function (event) {

        var $target = $(this);
        var $bf = $target.find('.booking_form');
        var hospital = $target.data('hospital-id');

        $bf.dialog();
        $bf.find('input#hospital_id').val(hospital);
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.booking_form .user_full_name').on('change', function (e) {
        this.form.submit();
    });

     $('.rota td').addClass("Half Full Semi-Foo");
});
```

What happens is that upon clicking the table cell the jquery dialog appears which enabling you to submit a booking form once selecting an employee. What I am trying to do now is extend this by using the [jQuery selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid) so that upon selecting a number of cells this would open a dialog so that you can submit a form multiple times. Example being that upon highlighting 3 cells this opens a dialog, upons selecting the `user_full_name` this submits the form 3 times.

Would this be easy as changing the following

```
$('.rota  td').live('click', function (event) {
```

to

```
$( "#rota td" ).selectable('click', function (event) {
```

Comment: what is your question? have you tried to do it yet?

Comment: See my update. My question is how do you get the selectable to work with the jquery-ui dialog. So that upon selecting a number of cells the dialog appears. I found something along the lines of this https://ehighlight.pagodabox.com/ From the homepage example you can select a number of boxes "dates" what I am trying to do upon selecting a number of table cells to open the jquery dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Selectable#events), you need to handle the `selected` event

```
$("#rota td").selectable({
   selected: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Or maybe the `stop` event?

Comment: Thanks for the response, so effectively I would end up with something like the following: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5193107 going to test if this works